# Get properties of nodes returned by allContactedBodies()?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to get a list of the objects touching a node. I used the function player.physicsBody.allContactedBodies. However I cannot read the name of the node nor it's contactBitMask. When trying to print the body.name I get the error "can't unwrap optional node"

Here's is what I'm trying now (scroll to the end for the allContactBodies() function):

```
let motionManager = CMMotionManager()
var player = SKShapeNode()
var world = SKShapeNode()
var ledge = SKShapeNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let worldSize = view.bounds.size
    self.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
    self.size = worldSize
    self.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFit
    self.name = "Universe"
    //self.physicsWorld.speed = 0.25 // DEBUG

    // Add world
    world = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: worldSize)
    world.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromPath: world.path)
    world.fillColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
    world.physicsBody.restitution = 0
    world.physicsBody.friction = 0.1
    world.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.size.width/2, self.frame.size.height/2) // Move camera
    world.name = "world"
    self.addChild(world)

    // Add player
    player = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.frame.size)
    player.physicsBody.restitution = 0
    player.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    player.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    player.physicsBody.allowsRotation = false
    player.name = "player"
    world.addChild(player)

    // Add ledge
    ledge = SKShapeNode(rectOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    ledge.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
    ledge.fillColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    ledge.strokeColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    ledge.physicsBody.dynamic = false
    ledge.position = CGPointMake(150, 100)
    ledge.name = "ledge"
    world.addChild(ledge)

    // Accelerometer updates
    motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates()
}


override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {
    let bodies = player.physicsBody.allContactedBodies()
    for body : AnyObject in bodies {
        println(String(body.name)) // Produces Error
    }
 }
```

If I println(body) the log shows:

```
<SKPhysicsBody> type:<EdgeLoop> representedObject:[<SKShapeNode> name:'world' accumulatedFrame:{{-0.49996948, -0.5}, {360.99997, 569}}]
```

How can I get the name and other properties of each node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error message, I guess the `body` didn't have a `node` (i.e., it was `nil`) and you tried to unwrap it to access the `name` of the node. You could test first:

```
if let node = body.node {
    if let name = node.name {
        println(name)
    } else {
        println("have node but no name")
    }
} else {
    println("body without node")
}
```

Comment: this worked, thakns! though I have no idea what the body without a node was.